# want to send mail notification to admin when user post comment using fb comment on drupal

Tags: drupal-7, facebook-social-plugins

There is no any module or settings for sending mail to admin when anyone posts fb comment in drupal site.

I have tried to add code using custom module.
I got the error :

> FB is not defined

Comment: It is done by using fb.init()

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no easy way or popular module to do that. Nevertheless, this remains possible with the facebook API.

If you tried this method https://www.drupal.org/node/1984880

and get a FB is not defined error; it is because you forgot to include facebook SDK.

You'll find here how to do that : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3

I hope this helps

Comment: I have developed drupal module and uploaded in drupal.org https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_comment_notification